# Selecting string value in column A based on value of column B in Power BI

Tags: string, filter, powerbi

I am having some problems in selecting a value for column "serial" based on the date in "application date".

What I would like to do is create a Measure which selects the appropriate serial value. In this case, as we are currently in May (as of this post), I would like to be able to read the value "532-sr" in the "serial" column based on the "application date" column.

And so, next month in June, this would automatically update to "632-sr"

I've tried various things but keep coming up with blanks values.
Any help would be appreciated. I've pasted a screen grab below to better illustrate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I've solved my own question.

```
Measure = CALCULATE( MAX( [serial] ), MONTH( [application date] ) = MONTH( NOW() ) ).
```

I was missing the MONTH() function in MONTH( [application date] )